# ORA-00937: not a single-group group function in 11g,12c

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle12c

Query1:

```
select 1 from (select count(*),col1 from table1);
```

O/P:
1

Version: 11g

Query2:

```
select * from (select count(*),col1 from table1);
```

O/P:
Error:

> Execution (1: 32): ORA-00937: not a single-group group function

Version: 11g

As, we are in same version, 
1. For Query2, why we are getting error?
2. With out group by how query1 is returning result?

In Version 12C, both queries are returning error as shared above.

Comment: Depending on your setting, the optimizer may remove some things from the query, and so you may end up, in 11 with an answer, and 12 an error. You surely know why you're having the error, at least I hope.

Comment: Looks like a bug. As a general rule: aggregates require GROUP BY clause for columns not being aggregated, so 12c's output seems to be appropriate as it raises the error.

Answer (score 2):

You should be getting the error for query 1 in 11g too. The fact that you don't may be down to [bug 16989676](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/BugDisplay?id=16989676), which affected 11gR2 and was fixed in 12cR1. You'll need a support account and contract to see the details - which I can't reproduce here. Suffice to say that it looks very similar; but mentions you can get the wrong results too (e.g. using `select count(*)` instead of `select 1`) - if you ignore the syntax being invalid, that is, since there is no correct result really.